# crystal report fail to load information error in file temp on client 32-bit and not on client 64-bit

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I'm getting crystal report error when i  deploy on  32-bit client machine but not getting error on 64-bit client machine.

in visual studio 2013 i have set TARGET CPU AS X86

on client machine have install cr runtime 32-bit

i have search on web but no specific answer
please can someone help

thank you for your time

[This is the pic of the  error that i'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72J3G.png)

Comment: We don't provide *urgent* help here. If you have a need for *urgent* help, hire a contractor and pay them a sufficiently high rate to get their immediate attention. Here your question is no more urgent than that of anyone else. It's also impossible to help you solve an *error* when you don't tell us what *error* it is. That information is right on the screen in front of you, and there is absolutely no reason for you not to share that information with us as well. You're asking for **free help** to solve **your problem**. You should be providing us with the details we need in order to help.

Comment: @ken white sorry i didn't  mean that my query is more important than others. And regarding the error as i mentioned it is showing as                                                               Failed to load database information error in file temp_xxxx_xx_{xxx}.rpt  Failed to load database information

Comment: Asking for *urgent* help is asking *Please give my question attention right now. Other people can wait, because my question is urgent and should be answered fast*. That's unfair to others. We're not anyone's private support system. It was good you edited that out, but you **still** did not explain what **error** you're getting. Please read my first comment again, and read all of it this time.

Comment: @ken white again i'm sorry but the intend was not so